# Why do my app use so huge memories?

Tags: ios, uitableview, memory-management, afnetworking

It always give me received memory warning when I ran this app on my iphone.
The app is very simple , when I pull down the UITableView ,it use AFNetWorking to download some html string ,and then I convert the html string to NSArray to show in UITableViewCell.The picture below shows it.
[image]

[image]

The method when I pull down the UITableView

```
- (void)loadNewData
{
_page=1;
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf=self;
[LZHThread loadForumFid:_fid page:_page completionHandler:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error) {
    if (error!=nil) {
        [LZHShowMessage showProgressHUDType:SVPROGRESSHUDTYPEERROR message:[error localizedDescription]];
    }else{
        weakSelf.threads=[array mutableCopy];
    }
    [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
    [weakSelf.tableView.header endRefreshing];
}];
}
```

THe below method is used to fetch data from Internet using AFNetworking

```
+(void)loadForumFid:(NSInteger)fid page:(NSInteger)page completionHandler:(LZHNetworkFetcherCompletionHandler)completion{
LZHHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager=[LZHHTTPRequestOperationManager sharedHTTPRequestOperationManager];
NSString *requestURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.hi-pda.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?fid=%ld&page=%ld",fid,page];
NSDictionary *requestParameters=@{@"fid":[NSNumber numberWithInteger:fid],
                                  @"page":[NSNumber numberWithInteger:page]};
[manager GET:requestURL
  parameters:requestParameters
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         NSString *responHtmlString=[NSString encodingGBKString:responseObject];
         [LZHHtmlParser extractThreadsFromHtmlString:responHtmlString completionHandler:completion];
     }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         completion(nil,error);
     }];
    }
```

The below method is used to fetch data from html string

```
+(void)extractThreadsFromHtmlString:(NSString *)html completionHandler:(LZHNetworkFetcherCompletionHandler)completion{
[LZHHtmlParser extractNoticeFromHtmlString:html];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSString *threadsString=html;
    NSRange range=[html rangeOfString:@"版块主题"];
    if (range.location!=NSNotFound) {
        threadsString=[html substringFromIndex:range.location];
    }
    NSMutableArray *threads=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSRegularExpression *regex=[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<span[\\s\\S]*?tid=(\\d*)[^>]+>(.*?)</a>([\\s\\S]*?)uid=(\\d+)\">(.*?)</a>[\\s\\S]*?<em>(.*?)</em>[\\s\\S]*?<strong>(.*?)</strong>/<em>(.*?)</em>" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    NSArray *matches=[regex matchesInString:threadsString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [threadsString length])];
    [matches enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSString *tid=[threadsString substringWithRange:[obj rangeAtIndex:1]];
        NSString *title=[threadsString substringWithRange:[obj rangeAtIndex:2]];
        NSString *hasImageOrHasAttach=[threadsString substringWithRange:[obj rangeAtIndex:3]];
        NSString *uid=[threadsString substringWithRange:[obj rangeAtIndex:4]];
        NSString *userName=[threadsString substringWithRange:[obj rangeAtIndex:5]];
        NSString *dateString=[threadsString substringWithRange:[obj rangeAtIndex:6]];
        NSString *replyString=[threadsString substringWithRange:[obj rangeAtIndex:7]];
        NSString *totalString=[threadsString substringWithRange:[obj rangeAtIndex:8]];
        BOOL hasImage=NO;
        BOOL hasAttach=NO;
        if ([hasImageOrHasAttach containsString:@"图片附件"]) {
            hasImage=YES;
        }else if([hasImageOrHasAttach containsString:@"附件"]){
            hasAttach=YES;
        }
        LZHUser *user=[[LZHUser alloc]initWithAttributes:@{LZHUSERUID:uid,
                                                           LZHUSERUSERNAME:userName}];
        LZHThread *thread=[[LZHThread alloc]initWithUser:user
                                              replyCount:[replyString integerValue]
                                              totalCount:[totalString integerValue]
                                                postTime:dateString
                                                   title:title
                                                     tid:tid
                                               hasAttach:hasAttach
                                                hasImage:hasImage
                                                 hasRead:[[LZHReadList sharedReadList] hasReadTid:tid]
                                       isUserInBlackList:[[LZHBlackList sharedBlackList]isUserNameInBlackList:userName]];
        if (!thread.isUserInBlackList) {
            [threads addObject:thread];
        }
    }];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (threads.count!=0) {
            completion(threads,nil);
        }else{
            completion(nil,[NSError errorWithDomain:@"无法获取帖子列表！" code:0 userInfo:nil]);
        }
    });
});
}
```

So why do I pull down UITableView , the memory grows , I pull down it many times ,the memory grows to hit a rather big number.It should be dealloc the array each time ,so the memory will not grow so rapidically . So how to fix it.

The cell for row at index path is

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *ID = @"cell";
LZHThreadTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ID];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[LZHThreadTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:ID];
}

[cell configureThread:self.threads[indexPath.row]];

//configure right buttons
cell.rightButtons = @[[MGSwipeButton buttonWithTitle:@"删除" backgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]],
                      [MGSwipeButton buttonWithTitle:@"黑名单" backgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.781 green:0.778 blue:0.801 alpha:1]]];
cell.rightSwipeSettings.transition = MGSwipeTransitionStatic;

cell.delegate=self;

cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
return cell;
}
```

And the configure cell method is below

```
-(id)configureThread:(LZHThread *)thread{
[_avatarImageView sd_setImageWithURL:thread.user.avatarImageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar"]];
_userNameLabel.text=thread.user.userName;
[_userNameLabel sizeToFit];
_countLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld/%ld",thread.replyCount,thread.totalCount];
[_countLabel sizeToFit];
_postTimeLabel.text=thread.postTime;
[_postTimeLabel sizeToFit];
_titleLabel.text=thread.title;
_titleLabel.numberOfLines=0;
_titleLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
CGSize optSize=[_titleLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width-2*kDistanceBetweenViews, 99999)];
_titleLabel.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, optSize.width, optSize.height);
if (thread.hasRead) {
    _titleLabel.textColor=kLightWordsColor;
    _userNameLabel.textColor=kLightWordsColor;
}else{
    _titleLabel.textColor=kDeepWordsColor;
    _userNameLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.622 blue:0 alpha:1];
    NSRange range=[_countLabel.text rangeOfString:@"/"];
    NSMutableAttributedString *countLableAttributedString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_countLabel.text];
    NSDictionary *attributes=@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.875 green:0.238 blue:0.238 alpha:1]};
    [countLableAttributedString addAttributes:attributes range:NSMakeRange(0, range.location)];
    _countLabel.attributedText=countLableAttributedString;
}
return self;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code?

Comment: I update the question ,could you see it again?

Answer (score 0):

To Load image on imageview what have you  done? For image the application memory size increase. So To load image on imageview you can you import  #import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h" is a AFnetworking api This will cache your memory and this will will also reduce memory pressure.

To load image on imageview You can use this method. I think this will be helpful for you.

**[imageCell.newsImageView setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"banner"]];**

Comment: Yes , i  used sdwebimage to download the image